# How to rename files in a drectory based on an existing array of names using Python?

Tags: python

I have some video files in a folder (E://Data/Video) with dummy names as

```
vid-dummyName.mp4
vid-dummyName (1).mp4
vid-dummyName (2).mp4
vid-dummyName (3).mp4
vid-dummyName (4).mp4
vid-dummyName (5).mp4
```

How can I use Python to rename them based on an exiting array like this:

```
import os

path = 'E:/Data/Video'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 1

names=['Not Dummy Video','Another Not Dummy Video','May be Dummy','Still Thinking','Give it a Name','Tomorrow']

for file in files:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str(i)+'.mp4'))
```

Comment: Try `for oldname, newname in zip(files, names): os.rename(os.path.join(path, oldname), os.path.join(path, '{}.mp4'.format(newname)))`. This assumes that the `files` list is in the same order as the `names` list.

Comment: Thanks but what is `zip` doing here?

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is a function that combines similarly indexed elements of multiple iterables. Basically `zip([1, 2], [3, 4])` returns `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`. That link provides more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 1-1 correspondence between 2 or more lists, `zip` would be the way to do it.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i, j in zip(a, b):
 print(i, j)

1 a
2 b
3 c
```

For your example, you'd need to `zip` `files` and `names` together, so that`files[i]` is renamed to `names[i]` for any `i`.

```
for i, j in zip(files, names):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), os.path.join(path, '{}.mp4'.format(j)))
```

---

You could also use `enumerate` to track the indices of the filenames from `os.listdir` and provide these indices to the `names` list while you are iterating:

```
for i, name in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, name), os.path.join(path, '{}.mp4'.format(names[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import os
path = "E:/Data/Video"
files = os.listdir(path)
saved_path = os.getcwd()
for file_ in files:
  os.rename(file_, file_+".mp4")
```